# Why there is not much percentage unit in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

Why there is not much percentage unit in tailwind like for example I wanted a width of 50%. I understand that I can add custom config to it but I just wanted to know is there any specific reason to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say this is more of a *personal preference* style of coding. After using [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/#what-is-tailwind), I realised that most of my styling can be **easily** and **flexibly** done by using [flex](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex) and [grid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns).

Taking your example of `width: 50%`

```
// using flex
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-1">1</div> // 50%
    <div class="flex-1">2</div> // 50%
</div>


// using grid
<div class="grid grid-cols-2">
    <div>1</div> // 50%
    <div>2</div> // 50%
</div>
```

As you suggested, one can simply add a custom width to the tailwind config as well.

Comment: thank you,  I was thought that there is some tricky case where percentage based unit is tricky or has a side effect

Answer (score -1):

just do this:

```
style={{width: width+'%'}}
```